# jQuery get attribute

Tags: jquery, ajax

There are many `class="item"` blocks on the page.

For each one there is different `var item_link` and ajax request.

Ajax searches for `src` attribute of `.message img` and throws it to `var src`.

```
$(".item").each(function(){
    var item_link = "http://...";
    $(this).prepend('<div class="src"></div>');
    $.get(item_link, function(data) {
        var src = $('.message img', data).attr('src');
    });
});
```

How to print `var src` to `<div class="src"></div>`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[jAndy's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053295/jquery-ajax-get/3053330#3053330) should work, but it waits to add the div until the `GET` completes (which should be fine). If it's really important that you put the div in place before doing the `GET`, though, you could do this:

```
$(".item").each(function(){
    var item_link = "http://...";
    var item_div = $('<div class="src"></div>');
    $(this).prepend(item_div);
    $.get(item_link, function(data) {
        var src = $('.message img', data).attr('src');
        item_div.text(src);
    });
});
```

That uses `item_div.text()`, which will show the value from `src`. If `src` has HTML tags and you want them to be rendered, use `item_div.html()` instead.

**Edit**: Update after your "doesn't work" comment:

The part you asked about, setting the text of the div, works fine. I think the problem is that your code is assuming that the `data` coming back from the `ajax` call will be a DOM element. It won't, it'll be a string until you insert it into the DOM somewhere (jQuery doesn't turn HTML into DOM objects proactively).

This version handles that:

```
$(".item").each(function(){
    var item_link = "http://...";
    var item_div = $('<div class="src"></div>');
    $(this).prepend(item_div);
    $.get(item_link, function(data) {
        var img = $(data).find('.message img'); // <== Make a DOM element, 
                                                //     look for images in
                                                //     .message containers
        var src = img.attr('src');
        item_div.text(src);
    });
});
```

Working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<title>Test Page</title>
<style type='text/css'>
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
</style>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
(function() {
    $(document).ready(pageInit);

    function pageInit() {
        $('#btnGo').click(go);
    }

    function go() {

        $(".item").each(function(index){
            var item_link = "tempserver.jsp?index=" + index;
            var item_div = $('<div class="src"></div>');
            $(this).prepend(item_div);
            $.get(item_link, function(data) {
                var img = $(data).find('.message img');
                var src = img.attr('src');
                item_div.text(src);
            });
        });

    }
})();
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type='button' id='btnGo' value='Go'>
<div>
    <div class='item'>Item 1</div>
    <div class='item'>Item 2</div>
    <div class='item'>Item 3</div>
    <div class='item'>Item 4</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

tempserver.jsp:

```
<div>
<div class='message'><img src='image<%=request.getParameter("index")%>.png'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Happy: Just did an edit, the problem isn't in the part that I thought you were asking about, but I think I found it.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$(".item").each(function(){
   var item_link = "http://...";       
   $.get(item_link, $.proxy(function(data) {
     var src = $('.message img', data).attr('src');
     $(this).prepend('<div class="src">' + src + '</div>');
   }, this));
});
```

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: indeed, I'll remove the first part

Comment: this solution gives nothing, div.src doesnt create

Comment: div.src must be original for each .item

Comment: @Happy: do you want the returned data to be the ID of the newly created div?

Comment: script must throw returned data into div.src, which is unical for each .item

Comment: @Happy: I don't understand what you mean with that. Please give an example of how it **should** look like.

Comment: @jAndy - The meaning of `this` changes inside the `$.get()` callback. You need to cache it in a variable outside.